# Converting ERDs in visio 2016 to SQL Script to create tables

Tags: sql, relational-database, visio, erd

As the title describes, is there a way to convert ERDs in visio 2016 to SQL Script to create tables? I'm using the crow's foot database notation diagram.

I've tried viso forward engineer but it cannot install on my Win10 x64 machine.